# How to use "menu_order" field for posts?

Tags: wp-admin, menu-order

I have a special case where I'd like to order posts in a custom order and it would be great to use the "menu_order" field that is normally only used for pages. What would be the best way to expose that in the WordPress admin UI?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Apparently it's as easy as:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'posts_order_wpse_91866' );

function posts_order_wpse_91866() 
{
    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );
}
```

And then doing the query:

```
$order_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
) );
```

Comment: Glad I asked. I was thinking I'd need to add a custom meta box and just save to the posts table manually.

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't work with Gutenberg. Here is an updated version that works: https://gist.github.com/chrisguitarguy/1301501

Comment: hooking into "admin_init" worked for me